# max_replication_slots in RDS replica

Tags: replication, postgresql-13

We have enabled the `on-prem PostgreSQL (Source) to AWS-RDS (Target)` replication by following the official [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-postgresql-from-on-premises-or-amazon-ec2-to-amazon-rds-using-logical-replication/) and which is worked well. Our RDS cluster has multiple replica's and am trying the enable the different replications for each replica and noticed it's failing due to the following error.

```
 | 2021-12-01T15:53:49.000+00:00Copy2021-12-01 15:53:49 UTC::@:[12142]:
ERROR:  could not register pglogical worker: all background worker slots are already used 
| 2021-12-01 15:53:49 UTC::@:[12142]:
```

Do the replication slot in target(RDS) `max_replication_slots` is set in cluster level? Is that possible to set it in the `replica` level? Or to enable every replication do we need to add `10` slots? How many  Slots we can open in maximum? The current RDS cluster config is given below.

```
dev=> select name, setting from pg_settings where name in ('wal_level','track_commit_timestamp','max_worker_processes','max_replication_slots','max_wal_senders  ','shared_preload_libraries');
           name           |                setting
--------------------------+---------------------------------------
 max_replication_slots    | 10
 max_worker_processes     | 10
 shared_preload_libraries | rdsutils,pglogical,pg_stat_statements
 track_commit_timestamp   | off
 wal_level                | logical
(5 rows)

dev=>
```